# Using a SwiftUI List Sidebar in a UISplitViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui, uisplitviewcontroller, sidebar, ios14

I am attempting to build my app's navigation such that I have a UISplitViewController (triple column style) with my views built with SwiftUI.  My Primary Sidebar is currently quite simple:

```swift
struct PrimarySidebarView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List(PrimarySidebarSelection.allCases, id: \.self, selection: $appModel.primarySidebarSelection) { selection in
            Text(selection.rawValue)
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
}
```

where PrimarySidebarSelection is an enum.  I am planning to access the same AppModel environment object in my other sidebar, allowing me to change what is displayed in the Supplementary Sidebar, depending on the Primary Selection.  I am using the new SwiftUI App life-cycle, rather than an AppDelegate.

I would like to know how to change the style of selection from this to the typical sidebar selection style that is used in SwiftUI's NavigationView.  According to [SwiftUI's List Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/init(selection:content:)-4sffx) the selection is only available when the list is in edit mode (and the selection shows the circle next to each item, which I do not want, instead I want the row to highlight like how it does in NavigationView when working with NavigationLinks).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum PrimarySidebarSelection: String, CaseIterable {
    case a,b,c,d,e,f,g
}
struct SharedSelection: View {
    @StateObject var appModel: AppModel = AppModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            PrimarySidebarView().environmentObject(appModel)
            Text(appModel.primarySidebarSelection.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var primarySidebarSelection: PrimarySidebarSelection = .a
}
struct PrimarySidebarView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(PrimarySidebarSelection.allCases, id: \.self) { selection in
                Button(action: {
                    appModel.primarySidebarSelection = selection
                }, label: {
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text(selection.rawValue)
                            .foregroundColor(selection == appModel.primarySidebarSelection ? .red : .blue)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                )
                .listRowBackground(selection == appModel.primarySidebarSelection ? Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemBackground) : Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
            }
            
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something very similar to this, I just wanted to be able to have the default sidebar UI of each respective platform, but I guess this will just have to make-do for now.